# Remove country billing and shipping fields on admin add order in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, orders

In the admin, when you click Add Order, I can't figure out how to remove the billing & shipping country fields.  I don't want to use CSS to just hide the fields because I need the country hidden when viewing the order on the frontend (form-pay.php).

I tried the following normal way of removing those fields from checkout but it has no effect here.

```
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove shipping and billing country fields on admin add new order page, you will use the following:

```
// Admin billing fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'custom_admin_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_admin_billing_fields( $billing_fields ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow === 'post-new.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'shop_order' ){
        unset($billing_fields['country']); // remove billing country field
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}

// Admin shipping fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields', 'custom_admin_shipping_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_admin_shipping_fields( $shipping_fields ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow === 'post-new.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'shop_order' ){
        unset($shipping_fields['country']); // remove shipping country field
    }
    return $shipping_fields;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That does remove the fields, however on the "Customer Payment Page" it still shows the billing & shipping country.  $order->get_formatted_billing_address must be defaulting to the only country I ship to?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis You asked in your question to remove the billing and shipping fields from Admin order creation page… My code does that and should be accepted. If you have another question, make a new question and I will be happy to answer it. On Form pay page there is no address displayed…

Comment: read the 2nd part of the question " I need the country hidden when viewing the order on the frontend (form-pay.php)."

Comment: O yeah,  I forgot, I added those fields into the template, giving the customer the option to edit their billing & shipping via ajax.

Comment: I will make a new question about removing country from $order->get_formatted_billing_address.  thanks.

Comment: nevermind, I can just use $order->get_billing_first_name(), etc. to echo out all the values needed instead of get_formatted_billing_address()

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Yes you can as it's on your existing customization :)